# How to increment a foor loop within a nested if statement

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, increment

Im distinguishing 2 players in TicTacToe by utilising MOD, which is used upon an incrementing for loop. Im having trouble incrementing the foor loop within a nested if statement.

```
            for i in range (1,10):
                if i % 2==1:
                    #1st row
                    if click[0]<=250 and click[0]>=100 and click[1]<=250 and click[1]>=100:
                        current_game[0][0] = "X"
                        i+=1
                    elif click[0]<=550 and click[0]>=250 and click[1]<=250 and click[1]>=100:
                        current_game[0][1] = "X"
                        i += 1
                    elif click[0]<=700 and click[0]>=550 and click[1]<=250 and click[1]>=100:
                        current_game[0][2] = "X"
                        i += 1
                    #2nd row
                    elif click[0]<=250 and click[0]>=100 and click[1]<= 550and click[1]>=250:
                        current_game[1][0] = "X"
                        i += 1
                    elif click[0]<=550 and click[0]>=250 and click[1]<=550 and click[1]>=250:
                        current_game[1][1] = "X"
                        i += 1
                    elif click[0] <= 700 and click[0] >= 550 and click[1] <= 550 and click[1] >= 250:
                        current_game[1][2] = "X"
                        i += 1
                    #3rd row
                    elif click[0]<=250 and click[0]>=100 and click[1]<= 700and click[1]>=550:
                        current_game[2][0] = "X"
                        i += 1
                    elif click[0] <= 550 and click[0] >= 250 and click[1] <= 700 and click[1] >= 550:
                        current_game[2][1] = "X"
                        i += 1
                    elif click[0] <= 700 and click[0] >= 550 and click[1] <= 700 and click[1] >= 550:
                        current_game[2][2] = "X"
                        i += 1
                elif i % 2==0:
                    # 1st row
                    if click[0] <= 250 and click[0] >= 100 and click[1] <= 250 and click[1] >= 100:
                        current_game[0][0] = "o"
                        i += 1
                    elif click[0] <= 550 and click[0] >= 250 and click[1] <= 250 and click[1] >= 100:
                        current_game[0][1] = "o"
                        i += 1
                    elif click[0] <= 700 and click[0] >= 550 and click[1] <= 250 and click[1] >= 100:
                        current_game[0][2] = "o"
                        i += 1
                    # 2nd row
                    elif click[0] <= 250 and click[0] >= 100 and click[1] <= 550 and click[1] >= 250:
                        current_game[1][0] = "o"
                        i += 1
                    elif click[0] <= 550 and click[0] >= 250 and click[1] <= 550 and click[1] >= 250:
                        current_game[1][1] = "o"
                        i += 1
                    elif click[0] <= 700 and click[0] >= 550 and click[1] <= 550 and click[1] >= 250:
                        current_game[1][2] = "o"
                        i += 1
                    # 3rd row
                    elif click[0] <= 250 and click[0] >= 100 and click[1] <= 700 and click[1] >= 550:
                        current_game[2][0] = "o"
                        i += 1
                    elif click[0] <= 550 and click[0] >= 250 and click[1] <= 700 and click[1] >= 550:
                        current_game[2][1] = "o"
                        i += 1
                    elif click[0] <= 700 and click[0] >= 550 and click[1] <= 700 and click[1] >= 550:
                        current_game[2][2] = "o"
                        i += 1
```

I want to be able to increment the for loop if someone clicks on a certain co-ordinate space.

Comment: Replace `for i in range (1,10):` with `while i<10` and add `i =1` before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `for i in range(1, 10)`, it doesn't matter what changes you make to `i` during an iteration, when it comes back to the `for` loop it will be assigned the next value in the `range`. example:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    i += 2
```

What you expect to happen is something like

```
>>> 0
>>> 3
```

but what actually will happen is this:

```
>>> 0
>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 3
>>> 4
```

What happened here? First,`i` is assigned the value `0`, then it was printed and increment (so now it is equal to 2). Next, `i` is assigned the value `1` (from the `range` generator), so the increment you made was overridden.

To solve this use a `while` loop:

```
i = 1
while i < 10:
    # do stuff
    i += 1
```

Now the value of `i` will not be overridden every time the `loop` executes

Answer (score 0):

The expression `range(n)` is evaluated just once, not on every iteration. You can't set n and expect the `range(n)` be changed. It doesn't allow this. [Check it here for details](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)

You have to use while loop for that.

```
i=0
while i<=5:
    #do your tasks
    #do your increment
```